# Google Apps Script の AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.get()の挙動に関して

Tags: google-apps-script

□ 事象
関数 `AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.get()` を使用してGoogleグループの情報を
取得を行っていたのですが、最近、次のようなエラーメッセージが表示され
情報が取得できなくなりました。

□ 実行スクリプト

```
function getGroupSettingsTest() {
  var groupId = 'group1@testdomain.com';

  try{
    // 指定したグループIDの情報を取得する
    var group = AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.get(groupId);

    // 取得した情報をログ出力する
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(group, null, 2));
  }catch(e){
    // エラー内容をログ出力する
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

□ エラーメッセージ

```
[19-06-03 18:20:38:823 PDT] GoogleJsonResponseException: 次のエラーが発生し、
groupsSettings.groups.get の呼び出しに失敗しました: A system error has occurred
```

□ お願い
対象のグループの情報を取得できるようにしたいと思います。
原因または切り分けのポイントがありましたら教えていただけないでしょうか。

エラーが発生した groupIdのグループが存在していることは確認しています。
変数 groupId の値を、別の値(group2@testdomain.com)に変更して実行すると、
正しく情報が取得できました。そのため、エラーが発生した groupId 側に
何か原因（Googleグループの機能更新等で新たに設定が必要となったなど）があるのではないかと考えています。